# passing multivariables to new page via gridview select

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview where i want to pass two different ID when i select a row to a new page.
I need them to be two different variables so i dont want to bind them together.

Currently, the way i am doing it with link select the values of SUBMITTEDJOBAPPLICATION & the
JOBAPPLICATIONID variables are the same(which is incorrect). What i mean is the SUBMITTEDJOBAPPLICATION is correct but the
JOBAPPLICATIONID is the same as SUBMITTEDJOBAPPLICATION and that is incorrect.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSelect" runat='server' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/UnscreenedApplicantPage.aspx?SubmittedID={0}&jobID={0}", Eval("SUBMITTEDJOBAPPLICATION"), Eval("JOBAPPLICATIONID")) %>'>Select</asp:HyperLink>
```

How can  i remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change     `SubmittedID={0}&jobID={0}`

to

```
SubmittedID={0}&jobID={1}
```

in `String.Format("SubmittedID={0}&jobID={0}", Eval("SUBMITTEDJOBAPPLICATION"), Eval("JOBAPPLICATIONID"))` you only use zero index so fist parameter will replace both places.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSelect" runat='server' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/UnscreenedApplicantPage.aspx?SubmittedID={0}&jobID={1}", Eval("SUBMITTEDJOBAPPLICATION").ToString(), Eval("JOBAPPLICATIONID").ToString()) %>'>Select</asp:HyperLink>
```

You need `Eval("SUBMITTEDJOBAPPLICATION").ToString(), Eval("JOBAPPLICATIONID").ToString()` as well.